# analysing binary image data to determine format

Tags: image, colors, analysis, color-palette

I have some binary data representing an image to be used as a texture on an OpenGL based system.

I'm trying to determine the actual format of this image... eg: RGBA, RGB5_A1, RGB8...

From a brute force approach, I get the best results drawing it as RGB5_A1, though it appears smaller than it should.

Attempts to render it as GL_RGB5 produce the right size, but the image is rendered as entirely white.

GL_RGBA8 produce an image that is both too small, and too dark.

Note that I do not need to determine the format programatically. I only need to determine the format of this particular texture. I couldn't even tell you what the colour depth is.

I do know what it 'should' look like, once it's rendered.

Are there any tools available to assist with this? Something that will render the texture in all possible formats and allow me to view them?

Comment: I find ImageMagick very helpful for manipulating images, e.g. turning raw data into a viewable format.  And you can script it so you could output a range of possible images.  I'm not sure how it handles 16bit RGB(A?) data though.